Hair particles overlap in collection
I've been working on making a 3D image in blender based off of an old Miniature set I made in Sculpty years ago.

I sculpted a rough looking hand as a mesh in Blender, but when I added particles to it, they overlap

If anyone has any advice, it'd be greatly appreciated.
